# Collapsing many duplicate user IDs and many columns into unique user ID table

Tags: sql-server

Original data set:

- Rows are events, each has unique user ID as a column, and user IDs are repeated across different events
- There are 5 columns that track condition codes associated with the event - CODE1 through CODE5, which all draw from the same set of possible code values. Events have between 0 and 5 codes associated with them

Goal Table:

- Rows are unique user IDs
- Column headers represent all unique values of the CODE columns (~30 possible), so 30 columns total
- Each cell contains a 0 or 1 counting whether, across any event, that user had the column condition code attached to it

In excel I would have added all 30 columns to the original data set, created 1s/0s in those cells, then used a sumproduct double unary function to pull into the unique user ID table but unfamiliar with options in SQL

Comment: Can you add some sample input data and the expected result?

Answer (score 0):

OK - answering my own question.

Used the "Unpivot" operator on the columns, joined the table with condition scores to that skinnier table, and then added up by unique member across all the scores.

Doesn't get me to the table output I wanted, but it gets me the answer reasonably efficiently.